# Get a list of every PrintQueue in C# for PrintDialog

Tags: c#, printing

Getting a list of printer names is easy, using `System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` but I need a PrintQueue object in order to use it with a `PrintDialog`.

How can I get a list of every `System.Printing.PrintQueue` available using C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` static property and resolving each `System.Printing.PrintQueue` by name:

```
public static IEnumerable<PrintQueue> GetAllPrinterQueues()
{
    using (var printServer = new LocalPrintServer())
    {
        foreach (string printerName in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.OfType<string>())
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(printerName, @"(?<machine>\\\\.*?)\\(?<queue>.*)");
            yield return match.Success ?
                new PrintServer(match.Groups["machine"].Value).GetPrintQueue(match.Groups["queue"].Value) :
                printServer.GetPrintQueue(printerName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question about disposing: on the one hand you use `using (var printServer = new LocalPrintServer())` so the local printserver will be disposed but on the other hand you use `new PrintServer(match.Groups["machine"].Value).GetPrintQueue(match.Groups["queue"].Value)` without disposing the created print server. Is there a reason behind it? I'm a bit concerned by using the `GetPrintQueue(printerName)` result after (in local case) disposing its source.